# Insert chinese character to mysql db using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I would like to ask why the code shown below, cannot insert the chinese character `$split 5` to the MySQL db. I have created a `db` using `utf8_general_ci` and table as well.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS["mysql_host"], $GLOBALS["mysql_user"], $GLOBALS["mysql_passwd"], $GLOBALS["mysql_database"]);
$stmt = mysql_query("SET character_set_results 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cell (`add`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $split[5]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You have globals turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a typo. You've used `mysql_query()` instead of `mysqli_query()`

---

Following the mysqli documentation in PHP, `mysqli_set_cahrset()` is the way to go:

```
$mysqli->set_charset ('utf8');
```

So I would add the line above and remove the `mysql_query('SET ...');` statement

Comment: According to the PHP documentation this is not recommended. See: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Don't you mean `SET NAMES utf8`? `utf` is not a valid character set.

Comment: Thank you both! :) utf was just a typo. But didn't know about `mysqli_set_charset()`